# Django filter: Collect filtered data from multiple Models(Same Type) into one view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-tables2, django-filters

I have four different Models with same structure(Same number of columns and same column name), The four models belong to different category. I want to filter data from each of the models using some filter fields and, I want this same filters to be applicable to all the models at same instance and show all of the filtered data from all the models into one view.
I am using django-filters third party library. Here is a sample filter for a Model.

filters.py

```
import django_filters
from django_select2 import *
from django_filters import STRICTNESS
from django_filters.widgets import RangeWidget
from InputForms.models import Reportable

class RFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
Date = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(widget=RangeWidget(attrs={'placeholder': 'YYYY/MM/DD'}))
class Meta:
    model = Reportable
    fields = ['Cause','TypeOfEmployee','Date','UnitName','Shift']

    strict = STRICTNESS.RETURN_NO_RESULTS
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .filters import *
from InputForms.models import Reportable

def RFView(request):
    f = RFilter(request.GET, queryset=Reportable.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'filter': f,'Header':"Reportable"})
```

template.html

```
<h3>{{ Header }}</h3>
<form action="" method="get">
    {{ filter.form.as_table }}
    {{ list_filter }}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% render_table filter.qs %}
```

Comment: Although I don't have all information on hand, I'd recommend restructuring your database. If all the models are 'the same' why aren't they just the same? You could add a flag (a `CharField` with `choices`?) to differentiate between the different 'categories'. This'd make your issue trivial to fix as there wouldn't be one in the first place.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but I have tons of data and It will be difficult to manage that much if i have only model. Is there any way to apply the filters to all the models?